# uninitialized constant DocumentsController::PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying for a couple of hours to get PDFKit working with my app.

I am getting an error of `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf`  when I try to generate a pdf.

The pdfkit gem is installed
wkhtmltopdf is installed and seems to be running ok

```
mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

.

```
pdfkit.rb
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
end
```

My Show def in the documents Controller includes

```
pdf = PDFKit.new('test')
send_data(pdf.to_pdf)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @document }
  format.csv { send_data @documents.as_csv }
```

Note that there is no format.pdf

application.rb has

```
require 'pdfkit'
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware
```

If I go to my documents index it shows OK. If I add .pdf, I get

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in DocumentsController#index
ActionController::UnknownFormat

Rails.root: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/development/research_library_new

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:40:in `index'
```

It appears that it is looking for format.pdf in the respond_to block

If I try to show one of the documents, I get

```
NameError in DocumentsController#show
uninitialized constant DocumentsController::PDFKit

Rails.root: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/development/research_library_new

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:84:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"10"}
```

I checked with a rake middleware and pdfkit is installed as middleware.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but did you restart the app after installing the gem?

Comment: No problem - Yes, I am running it on a Puma server and have been restarting after every change I've tried.

Comment: @standelaune - Thanks to your question, I found a major error on my part. I use always up on the server (1) I was not running bundle install after uploading to the server and (2) I was restarting the wrong rails server (Similarly named to the one I was using).. I was wondering why the page was ready so quickly after I restarted the server.. It usually takes about 60 seconds.. Well, it was because I was restarting the wrong server.

Comment: glad you got it working ;)